# (LibreOffice) Replace every character in a selection with *

Tags: libreoffice, text-processing, odt

I want to shadow portions of a `.odt` document with stars for every character in the selection area. I guess it should be possible using the `find and replace` tool in LibreOffice. Just need to know how to tell it to find every character, some thing like a wildcard star character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

In **Edit** → **Find and Replace** dialog box,

- enter a single dot (`.`) into the **Find:** input box,
- enter a star (`*`) into the **Replace:** input box,
- select **Current selection only**,
- select **Regular expressions**, and
- click **Replace All**.

Additionally: If you want to replace with stars *only the non-blank characters*, you may use `[^ ]` in the **Find:** input box.