# Replace multiple occurences of a character with a single character in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice

In LiberOffice Calc, I would like to replace multiple occurences of a character with a single occurence. For example, **abcd::::xyz** should be replaced with **abcd:xyz**. How to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make a copy of the document before you try this out just in case it doesn't work how you want it to. Does this answer your question? [(LibreOffice) Replace every character in a selection with \*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391158/libreoffice-replace-every-character-in-a-selection-with)

Comment: @mchid I'm afraid not. The solution replaces every character with a replacing character. It does not diminish the occurrence count to 1.

Comment: The answer is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Edit > Find and Replace*. Make sure *Regular Expressions* is checked.

- **Find** `(.)\1+`
- **Replace** `$1`

Explanation: `(.)` finds any character and remembers what it is. `\1` refers to whatever character was found originally, and `+` requires 1 or more of them. `$1` also refers to that same character.

Example: `apple bannanna` becomes `aple banana`

To change only semicolons, do this instead:

- **Find** `(:){2,}`
- **Replace** `$1`

Documentation: https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/01/02100001.html

Comment: Marvellous! Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

On your top menu, click on **EDIT**.

Then, select **Find & Replace**.

In the **Find** field, enter `::::`

In the **Replace** field, enter `:`

Then, click **Replace All**.

Finally, click **Done** and then click **Close**

Comment: This does work only for the example specified, it is not scalable.